# How to automatize database changing from mysql to mongodb in laravel

Tags: database, mongodb, laravel, dependency-injection

I want to automatize database dependencies when I change database connection from Mysql to Mongodb .

I'm using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb for laravel mongodb database , for use this library I should extend my models from it's specefic model ,
I want to change my database connection from mysql to mongodb on run time and when changing database its dependencies ( for example extending it's model ) be done automatically.

this is laravel model implementation :

```
abstract class Model implements ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Jsonable, 
JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable {
  it's codes .... 
}
```

and this is library model implementation :

```
abstract class Model extends BaseModel {
   it's codes .... 
}
```

I add these codes in my RouteServiceProvider.php for replace library model instead of laravel model :

```
if (config('database.default') == 'mongodb') {
       $this->app->bind(
            'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
            'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model'
        );
}
```

I know I can only use dependency injection in constructor or method , and in this case I don't have constructor and I don't know how to use constructor injection for it ( because both of them are abstract class and my models should extend library class not just call it's special methods ), then it definitely wont work .

Does any body have a solution ?

Comment: can you show us the error ? btw you don't use the decorator pattern but the strategy pattern.

Comment: it says : vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : Call to a member function prepare() on null , because models didn't Inherit from library model  it Has caused this error . @DjellalMohamedAniss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it's answer myself and I share it's solution for other people will have same question :

**first**, you have to define **Alise Class** (for example : DBModel) in config/app.php :

```
'aliases'=> [
    ...
    'DBModel' => ''

]
```

**then** , you have to inherit all models that you want to have dynamic connection :

in models class :

```
use DBModel ;
class Comment extends DBModel {
...
}
```

**finally** , in your serviceProvider at boot function add these codes :

```
if (config('database.default') == 'mysql') {
   $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
   $loader->alias('DBModel', \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class);
} else if (config('database.default') == 'mongodb') {
  $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
  $loader->alias('DBModel', \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model::class);
}
```

don't forget to use **Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader** on top of file .